# How to pass value from one cs-file (void!) to another?

Tags: c#, xml, json, winforms

my little program works very well, reading an xml file with 3 config values, reading a json-http-page and so on.
now there is a little thing i want to do: display the values out of the xml in my settings dialogue. i got this (Program.cs):

```
using ...

//*****************************************************************************
namespace t2bl
{
abstract class TANSS2BL
{



    public static NotifyIcon notico;


    //==========================================================================


    public static void Main(string[] astrArg)
    {
        ContextMenu cm;
        MenuItem miCurr;

        cm = new ContextMenu();

        miCurr = new MenuItem();
        miCurr.Index = 0;
        miCurr.Text = "&Settings";
        miCurr.Click += new System.EventHandler(SettingsClick);
        cm.MenuItems.Add(miCurr);

        miCurr = new MenuItem();
        miCurr.Index = 1;
        miCurr.Text = "Beenden";
        miCurr.Click += new System.EventHandler(ExitClick);
        cm.MenuItems.Add(miCurr);

        notico = new NotifyIcon();
        notico.Icon = new Icon("tanss.ico");
        notico.Text = "TANSS Busylight Connector";
        notico.Visible = true;
        notico.ContextMenu = cm;
        notico.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(NotifyIconDoubleClick);




        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();





        Application.Run();




    }

    public static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("C://bll.config.xml");

        XmlNode xmlurl = doc.SelectSingleNode("/settings/url");
        string url = xmlurl.FirstChild.Value;
        XmlNode xmluid = doc.SelectSingleNode("/settings/userID");
        string userid_string = xmluid.FirstChild.Value;
        XmlNode xmlrefresh = doc.SelectSingleNode("/settings/refresh");
        string refresh_string = xmlrefresh.FirstChild.Value;

        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(userid_string);
        int refresh = 1000 * (Convert.ToInt32(refresh_string));

        var controller = new BusylightUcController();


        while (true)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var downloadString = client.DownloadString(url + "/module/busylight.php?    user=" + userid);

            JObject colors = JObject.Parse(downloadString);
            //Console.WriteLine(colors["color"]); //Debug
            var colorStatus = Convert.ToInt32(colors["color"]);

            switch (colorStatus)
            {
                check the colors and set the light
            }
            Thread.Sleep(refresh);
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }



    //==========================================================================
    protected static void ExitClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notico.Dispose();
        Application.Exit();
    }

    //==========================================================================
    protected static void SettingsClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>

        // This should open the "Settings"-Popup, containing 3 textboxes and a button to    save them to xml.
        SettingsDiag form1 = new SettingsDiag();
        form1.Show();
    }

    //==========================================================================
    protected static void NotifyIconDoubleClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }



}
}
```

and on the other side this (Form1.Designer.cs):

```
namespace Settingsdialog
{
    partial class SettingsDiag
    {

    /// <summary>
    /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">True, wenn verwaltete Ressourcen gelöscht werden sollen; andernfalls False.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Vom Windows Form-Designer generierter Code

    /// <summary>
    /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
    /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 28);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(163, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "TANSS Busylight connector v1.0";
        this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(53, 65);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(159, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(271, 117);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "TANSS Busylight connector";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }


    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;

}
```

}

How do i pass the values "url", "userid_string", "refresh_string" from the backgroundworker void to the "textbox1.Text=" Output?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not so clear what you really want to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish that, one you had in other answers, I can suggest another one:
Because your worker is set to run async, you can for example, report the update progress using the worker event and then in the handler update the textbox

```
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bw.ProgressChanged += (o, args) => { textBox1.Text = args.UserState.ToString();}
```

It's clear that in your `bw.DoWork`event handler you need to report the progress operation passing the UserState as the string value you want to report and update, so inside the event handler you need to call

`bw.ReportProgress(0, "you value to report");`

hope this helps

Comment: Mh didnt get it to work as expected... I stopped working on that for now. Going to do some test-applicationswith bg_worker reports first. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate to your form the result of the background worker you could define your form as a member of TANSS2BL (and init it in Main).
Then in bw_DoWork you can call a method on your form with the information you want to display as parameters.

As bw_DoWork is on another thread don't forget to test InvokeRequired and BeginInvoke in your form before setting your textBox value.